# Can I repeat the clock tower jumping puzzle on a different character for more loot?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The Halloween event added an *infuriatingly difficult* jumping puzzle: The Mad King's Clock Tower. I managed to finish it yesterday on my air-specced Elementalist (that +35% movement speed helped!) and got a few items from the chest at the end. I completed it again today on that character and only got 8 Trick Or Treat bags.

So I thought I'd try clearing it on my Guardian. After an hour of falling to my death, I'm about ready to ragequit. Do I get any new rewards if I clear it on a different character, or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Oh, you. Come back after you do it on an asura while warriors in your group randomly "bless" you with swiftness from their warbanners. :P

Comment: The designer of the puzzle said he reckoned only 5% of players would reach the top. Hence why he put chests 1/3 and 2/3 of the way up for players who can't make it.

Comment: @DavidYell There's actually loot in those chests? I figured they were just decoys put there to slow people down...

Comment: @Brant Yes, but there's only Trick-or-Treat bags in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will receive another pair of the [Mad King's Slippers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mad_King%27s_Slippers), a [Spooky Skeleton Tonic](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spooky_Skeleton_Tonic), and a [Spooky Ghost Tonic](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Spooky_Ghost_Tonic) if you do the puzzle on another character (the same as the first time). The shoes for the first run on any character will be the appropriate armor type for them.

However, as you noted, you can only receive these once on a single character. All subsequent runs on the same character will reward Trick-or-Treat Bags.

Comment: I've never been so disappointed to hear that the answer to a question is "Yes, you can get more loot". :( Stupid clock tower.